# Protractor can find element but using .click(); causes it to not be found

Tags: angular, selenium-webdriver, xpath, protractor

I am having an issue where I can get my xpath to show zero errors on the test script if I use .isPresent(); to verify the element is on the page, but I get errors indicating the xpath cannot be found if I use a "click" command instead.
Here the xpath works:

```
element(by.xpath('//*[@id="layout-padding"]/ui-view/layout-authen/ui-view/div/div[2]/scroll-detector/settings-section[8]/div[1]/a/i')).isPresent();
```

Here the xpath of

```
element(by.xpath('//*[@id="layout-padding"]/ui-view/layout-authen/ui-view/div/div[2]/scroll-detector/settings-section[8]/div[1]/a/i')).click();
```

results in

> Failed: No element found using locator: By(xpath, //*[@id="layout-padding"]/ui-view/layout-authen/ui-view/div/div[2]/scroll-detector/settings-section[8]/div[1]/a/i)

Searching for the relative xpath for the text (which is probably safer in terms of future changes breaking it) like so `element(by.xpath('.//*[.="TextIWant"]')).isPresent();` works with `isPresent()` but fails with `.click()`.

I've tried different xpath tools (in Chrome and Firefox plus an add-on) to check the xpath but the result is the same. Why can this find the element but error when clicking on it? This script finds AND clicks on a few other elements before it gets to this point. What do I need to do to make it click on the element that it apparently CAN find?

Here is the element I copied:

```
div class="header"

a href="" class="toggle-bt ng-binding" ng-click="view.showContent = !view.showContent"
    i class="fa fa-angle-right" ng-class="view.showContent ? 'fa-angle-down' : 'fa-angle-right'" style=""></i>
    TextIWant
</a>

<div class="description ng-binding">
    Settings for the TextIWant
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Provide a relevant link or HTML code

Comment: Have you tried adding a wait for the element to be clickable? If the XPath you are using is in fact the same in both the present and click cases, you should not be getting this error unless it's a timing issue. A link to the page would help a lot.

Comment: When you say isPresent "works" that means it does not throw an error, or that if if you expect it to be true or truthy it is?

Comment: I added the element's code snippet. By isPresent works, I mean it doesn't throw an error. I did try a longer wait between the isPresent and the .click(); attempt, but I still got the error indicating it was not found for the click command.

Comment: I don't know the problem but for me sometimes it helped to use: 
`browser.actions().mouseMove(myElement).perform(); 
 browser.actions().click(myElement).perform();`

For example clicking on an `svg` drawn element did not work for me.

Comment: There are a lot of good ideas here, but I am wondering if it all is missing the point. From what you say, the xpath could be fine (or not fine in either case). What you are observing is that the thing is not there -- in either case (so maybe the locator needs work or maybe the thing really is not there). But isPresent should not give an error when the thing is not there (it should just return a promise that evaluates to false), but clicking on something that is not there should give an error.

Comment: I would not be surprised if it was the locator. I'm just not understanding why inspecting the element and copying its xpath has worked for many other elements but not for this one.

Answer (score 0):

please try the below one

`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.header div.description"))).isPresent();`
`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.header div.description"))).click();`

refer below for more info on css-selectors
http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/css-selectors-tutorial-for-selenium-with-examples

Answer (score 0):

It is possible element to be not clickable when you try to click it. Try this:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var elm = element(by.xpath('//*[@id="layout-padding"]/ui-view/layout-authen/ui-view/div/div[2]/scroll-detector/settings-section[8]/div[1]/a/i'));
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element(by.xpath('//*[@id="layout-padding"]/ui-view/layout-authen/ui-view/div/div[2]/scroll-detector/settings-section[8]/div[1]/a/i'))), 30000, "Element is not clickable").then(function() {
   elm.click();
});
```

Comment: Failed: unknown error: Element <i class="fa fa-angle-right" ng-class="view.showContent ? 'fa-angle-down' : 'fa-angle-right'"></i> is not clickable at point (362, 660). Other element would receive the click: <div class="es-footer ng-isolate-scope" ng-style="{'background': footerBg}" footer-bg="#E6E6E6" style="background: rgb(230, 230, 230);">...</div>
      (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.99)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565386 (45a059dc425e08165f9a10324bd1380cc13ca363),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.3 x86_64)

Comment: So that is progress. (presumably what you were trying to click on was not visible, hence the need for the scrolling) It is now finding the element, but Protractor can get fussy about clicking on a div or something when there is an input further inside, for example. Occasionally I give up and overrule it using an executeScript to do the click, but that is ugly. Does it help if you use @Sanja Paskova's code, but replace her locator with by.xpath('.//*[.="TextIWant"]' as you were thinking about? I'm wondering if that might be more precise in clicking on the part you mean.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their input and assistance. I was able to get a test to a passing but somewhat flaky state, so I do think (in addition to changing a few selectors) that timing was a factor too; the tests move very fast (a good thing) but I did see a few lags; those vary in the application.

Comment: Everything I've read about protractor (so far...my automation experience is different tools) indicates that it has the waits/sleeps built in to avoid adding those, and my tests do not pass at all without adding a few between screens. In past roles, timing was something that had to be worked out with trial and error, but I am seeing one part fail the most, and on one failed test run, protractor appeared to click the wrong element.

Answer (score 0):

Try with waits and javascript executor:

```
 var elm = element(by.xpath('//*[@id="layout-padding"]/ui-view/layout-authen/ui-view/div/div[2]/scroll-detector/settings-section[8]/div[1]/a/i'));
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element(by.xpath('//*[@id="layout-padding"]/ui-view/layout-authen/ui-view/div/div[2]/scroll-detector/settings-section[8]/div[1]/a/i'))), 30000, "Element is not clickable").then(function() {
   browser.executeScript('arguments[0].click()', elm);
});
```